# Can you practice latte art with UHT milk?

Tags: latte-art

I want to practise my latte art skills.

However, using fresh milk is quite expensive so my solution was to use long-life (UHT) milk, which is quite a bit cheaper than using fresh milk.

Will using UHT milk somehow affect this negatively?

Do you know of any other cost-effective ways of practising latte art?

Comment: Just to note that milk costs vary greatly from country to country. In the US (for example), fresh milk is way way *less* expensive than the shelf-stable packages.

Answer (score 6):

Back then when i got my first espresso machine i was recommended a method using a pinch of dishwashing soap in a pitcher with water. This way i was able to practice and enhance my frothing skills.

Be sure to find the correct dose of soap and be aware that soap residue can stick to the steamwand, so remember to clean it by purging the same way as you would froth milk.

I find this method much more suitable than wasting a lot milk if you intend to do it a couple of times a day for practicing.

Answer (score 4):

Some people don't like the "off" taste imparted by the Ultra-High Temperature ("UHT") process, but for the purposes of practicing your late art, foaming UHT should not be a problem. You'll find some subtle differences in the texture and physics of the UHT, but nothing significant enough to keep you from using it.

[Do you find a difference in frothing between UHT and 'regular' milk?](http://coffeegeek.com/forums/espresso/latteart/315911)